# prevent form from automatically re-submitting on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using jQuery to point a form's target to an iframe on .submit(). This is to upload a file. It works fine, but when the page reloads, and the iframe is appended to the DOM, the iframe automatically resubmits the form, causing the same file to be sent to the server on each page load.

If I do not include the iframe in the HTML markup, or do not append it to the DOM, this doesn't happen, but of course, I need the iFrame.

So my question is, how can i prevent this?

:)

Andrew

Comment: Can you show us the code you're presently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that if the iframe exists in the DOM when the user reloads the page, it will trigger the form again, so I simply didn't add the iframe until the user clicks to send the file.

The complete code (some is only relevant to my project, but the idea is there:

```
function uploadHandler()
{
    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie)
    {
        setTimeout(uploadComplete, 5);
    }
    else
    {
        uploadComplete(this);
    }
}


function uploadFile(e)
{

    if($('.uploadFrame').length > 0)
    {
        uploadiFrameNode.remove();
    }
    n = 'f' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
    uploadiFrameNode = $('<iframe class="uploadFrame invfr" src="about:blank" id="'+n+'" name="'+n+'"></iframe>');
    uploadiFrameNode.load(uploadHandler);
    $('body').append(uploadiFrameNode);
    formNode.attr('action', _ajaxPath  + "?drive=" + drive);
    formNode.attr('target', n);
    formNode.attr('method', 'POST');
    formNode.attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    formPathNode.val(tree[tree.length - 1].path);
}
function uploadComplete()
{
    refresh(tree[tree.length - 1].path);
    backToMenu();
    fileReset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

append the iframe to the document body on document ready.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").append("<iframe id='whatever' src='javascript:void(0)' />");
});
```